# Глубина конкретизации меток

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

Касательно этой темы: [Синонимизировать [div] и [html]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6226/%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-div-%d0%b8-html)

1. Нужны ли настолько уточняющие теги как `div`? Если нет, то почему, к примеру, мы оставляем такие теги как [android-textview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-textview)?
2. Если да, нужно ли синонимизировать такие теги?

Comment: Капитан очевидность предлагает опираться на практичность в этом вопросе: метки не нужны сами по себе, из любви к классификации и систематизации. Они нужны для поиска вопросов, давайте отсюда и рассуждать.

Comment: @AK но люди же их лепят и будут пытаться лепить, независимо от наших решений на мете.

Comment: @Suvitruf, тогда вывод очевиден: не бороться с непоборимым и лучше систематизировать, чем бесконечно вырезать глупые метки. Не можешь остановить что-то - возглавь это!